# Android DrawerLayout NavigationView exapandable menu item with one item fixed at bottom

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

what is latest way to implement expandable menu item with sign out as item at bottom fixed. on DrawerLayout NavigationView exapandable menu item should have a expandable item like this. I dont want to use library as library will be outdated with upgraded android version

```
MAIN
    Category 1 (+)
      item 1
      item 2
      item 3

SPECIAL
    Category 2 (+)
      item 5
      item 6
      item 7
```

I have below menu xml :

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_camara" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_gallery" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_manage" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_share" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                    android:title="Share" />
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_send" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                    android:title="Send" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="BNK">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_share_bnk" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                    android:title="Share BNK" />
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_send_bnk" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                    android:title="Send BNK" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Activity Code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.example.myapplication.ui.PersonAdapter;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private RecyclerView rr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        List<String> aa = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("text1","text2"));
        PersonAdapter personAdapter = new PersonAdapter(aa);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        rr = binding.rr;
        rr.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rr.setAdapter(personAdapter);
        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Activity Xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

App Bar xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content Main Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, my suggestion, to use RecyclerView and add expandable behabiour there, menu items is not enough flexible to achieve behaviour that you described.

Comment: Also, could you please share xml code with drawer to see the whole picture of the problem?

Comment: updated the code in description. i have added recyclerview as experiment to see if i can create an expandable menu item

Comment: Also, I think [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expandable-recyclerview-in-android-with-kotlin/) tutorial will help you to achieve expandable effect

Comment: needed a nested multilevel expandable effects, any suggestion for this